# Iterating js object and calling function

Tags: javascript, object

Referring to below question
[Iterate through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

If I want to iterate the object to search one function(given a function name in a variable) and then make a call to that function. How can I do it? I mean dynamically calling the function.

```
var libName = ''; //Get JS Library name from other source
var funName = ''; // Get function name from other source
var util = $.import("pathToJSLib",libName);
util.{call to function funName} // Call to function in funName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call it like this: `util[funName]()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [square bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation):

```
util[funName]();
```